# JMeter Bean Shell PostProcessor with embedded special characters

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am extracting a variable from the HTTPReponse body which contains a string containing special characters.  When I try to access the variablein the script, I am getting the following error.  Is there a way to access these vars while preserving the special characters?

jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of: `` token += "" + auQV8OGH47fz50YFm9rS/dQjTcUuGi55ryzC7S3YInNcaciCVR3/frSHwv8CE/mJD . . . '' Encountered "oSQ" at line 1, column 269.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are accessing JMeter Variable in your script body as `${variable_name_here}` which is not very recommended.

Beanshell should handle JMeter Variables without any issues given you access them via `vars` shorthand (or through "Parameters" section)

Given you have a JMeter Variable `${foo}` the correct ways of accessing its value will be:

1. Using `vars` shorthand:

   ```
   String foo = vars.get("foo");
   ```
2. Using "Parameters" section (assumes you have `${foo}` there)

   - String foo = Parameters;
   - String foo = bsh.args[0];

Demo:

[image: Beanshell different ways of accessing JMeter Variables]

Other troubleshooting techniques:

- You can add [debug()](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) command to the beginning of your script so debugging output will be printed into JMeter console window
- You can put your Beanshell code inside the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

  try {
      //your code here
  }
  catch (Throwable ex) {
      log.error("Beanshell failure", ex);
      throw ex;
  }

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on using Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests

Comment: Thanks!  What I was finally get to work was the following vars.get("c-sec-token").toString()